# GWT Editable Grid : How to replace cell widgets dynamically?

Tags: gwt, grid

I have created editable grid in which I am adding all the cell widgets. Now I want to check for some condition and replace a cell or column with another cell widget. For example if I have defined a column of EditTextCell, based on a boolean condition I have to change that column to have selectioncells(combo box). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to do that:

1. Use a `CompositeCell` with an `EditTextCell` and a `SelectionCell` and override the render method of the `CompositeCell` to render either the `EditTextCell` or the `SelectionCell` based on a boolean flag that you store in your `DTO`that is bound to the Cell.
2. Create a custom cell extending `AbstractEditableCell` for example (see this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html)) and implement the functionality yourself. You can check out the code for [SelectionCell](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SelectionCell.java&q=SelectionCell%20package%3ahttp://google-web-toolkit%5C.googlecode%5C.com) and [EditTextCell](http://www.google.com/codesearch#A1edwVHBClQ/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/EditTextCell.java) and copy most of it. In the render method you have to either display a dropdownlist or just a text based on the boolean flag.
3. Extend either `EditTextCell` or `SelectionCell` and implement the missing functionality. The advantage is that you can probably re-use some of the render methods and you don't have to write the complete render code yourself.